# Jitter dots without overlap

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, overlap, scatter

My data:

```
a <- sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE)
c <- sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
d <- sample(1:40, 100, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c, d)
```

Using `ggplot2`, I have created scatterplot over x = a and y = b, weighted in two dimension (by `colour = c` and `size = d`). Note that x and y are intentionally `1:5`.

Obviously, the points of different sizes and colors therefore overlap, so I tried jitter to avoid overlapping:

```
ggplot(df, aes(a, b, colour = c, size = d)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_jitter())
```

Now I would like the dots clustering closer together, so I tried several
combinations of `height` and `width` for the jitter function, such as

```
ggplot(df, aes(a, b, colour = c, size = d)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2, height = 0.2))
```

Jitter makes the dots still overlap and also distributes them to randomly on the given area.

Is there a way to have the dots not overlapping at all, yet clustered as close together as possible, maybe even touching and also not "side by side" or stacked? (In a way, creating kind of bubbles with smaller dots)?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to do it with `geom_dotplot` ? I have been playing with it for a few minutes but can't quite get it to do what you want.  But that is typically how I make stacked dotplots

Comment: @Reilstein: thanks for your help! Unfortunately, geom_dotplot keeps stacking the dots into one line and I also don't get different dot sizes...

Comment: Yup I had the same issue. I was able to get the dots in the right places, but was not able to map the color and size to them. It looks like ggbeeswarm is probably the way to go for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to @Tjebo's suggestions I have arranged dots in "heaps".

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 100
a <- sample(1:5,n,rep=TRUE)
b <- sample(1:5,n,rep=TRUE)
c <- sample(1:10,n,rep=TRUE)
d <- sample(1:40,n,rep=TRUE)
df0 <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

# These parameters need carefully tuning
minr <- 0.05
maxr <- 0.2
# Order circles by dimension
ord <- FALSE

df1 <- df0
df1$d <- minr+(maxr-minr)*(df1$d-min(df1$d))/(max(df1$d)-min(df1$d))
avals <- unique(df1$a)
bvals <- unique(df1$b)

for (k1 in seq_along(avals)) {
  for (k2 in seq_along(bvals)) {
  print(paste(k1,k2))
    subk <- (df1$a==avals[k1] & df1$b==bvals[k2])
    if (sum(subk)>1) {
      subdfk <- df1[subk,]
      if (ord) {
        idx <- order(subdfk$d)
        subdfk <- subdfk[idx,]
      }
      subdfk.mod <- subdfk
      posmx <- which.max(subdfk$d)   
      subdfk1 <- subdfk[posmx,]
      subdfk2  <- subdfk[-posmx,]
      angsk <- seq(0,2*pi,length.out=nrow(subdfk2)+1)
      subdfk2$a <- subdfk2$a+cos(angsk[-length(angsk)])*(subdfk1$d+subdfk2$d)/2
      subdfk2$b <- subdfk2$b+sin(angsk[-length(angsk)])*(subdfk1$d+subdfk2$d)/2
      subdfk.mod[posmx,] <- subdfk1
      subdfk.mod[-posmx,] <- subdfk2
      df1[subk,] <- subdfk.mod
    }
  }
}

library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
ggplot(df1, aes()) + 
  geom_circle(aes(x0=a, y0=b, r=d/2, fill=c), alpha=0.7)+ coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes!! That's most amazing! And exactly what I meant! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

An interesting visualization tool is the **beeswarm** plot.
In R the `beeswarm` and the `ggbeeswarm` packages implement this kind of plot.

Here is an example with `ggbeeswarm`:

```
set.seed(1234)
a <- sample(1:5,100,rep=TRUE)
b <- sample(1:5,100,rep=TRUE)
c <- sample(1:10,100,rep=TRUE)
d <- sample(1:40,100,rep=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
library(ggbeeswarm)
ggplot(aes(x=a, y=b, col=c, size=d),  data = df)+
  geom_beeswarm(priority='random',cex=3.5, groupOnX=T)+coord_flip()
```

[image]I hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I have tried several arguments in the ggbeeswarm and beeswarm but the dots keep being stacked either vertically or horizontally, as in your example. I guess that's due to the nature of my data (both x and y being c(1:5). using geom_jitter or geom_jitterdodge, the whole thing comes already quite close to what I want, but the dots overlap and some are jittered far away from the other dots.

Comment: *position_jitterdodge, apologies

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibile solution to the jittering problem of @Tjebo.
The parameter `dst` needs some tuning.

```
set.seed(1234)
a <- sample(1:5,100,rep=TRUE)
b <- sample(1:5,100,rep=TRUE)
c <- sample(1:10,100,rep=TRUE)
d <- sample(1:40,100,rep=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

dst <- .2

df.mod <- df
avals <- unique(df$a)
bvals <- unique(df$b)
for (k1 in seq_along(avals)) {
  for (k2 in seq_along(bvals)) {
    subk <- (df$a==avals[k1] & df$b==bvals[k2])
    if (sum(subk)>1) {
      subdf <- df[subk,]
      angsk <- seq(0,2*pi,length.out=nrow(subdf)+1)
      ak <- subdf$a+cos(angsk[-1])*dst
      bk <- subdf$b+sin(angsk[-1])*dst
      df.mod[subk,c("a","b")] <- cbind(ak,bk)
    }
  }
}

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df.mod, aes(a, b, colour = c, size = d)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you many times for this amazing solution! That works and looks great! Do you think that there might be a way to pack the dots closer together, i.e. not arranges in circles, but in "heaps"? I guess that I would need to play around with the cos/sin/dst parameters (?) but I don't really understand your function unfortunately, I am too much a beginner :/